# ruby array of arrays get duplicate string array

Tags: arrays, ruby, duplicates

I have this array of arrays:

```
arr =[["twitter.com", 9], ["twitter.com", 9], ["google.com", 11], ["paypal.me", 11],
      ["twitter.com", 11], ["yahoo.com", 12], ["google.com", 14], ["twitter.com", 17],
      ["twitter.com", 18], ["youtube.com", 31]]
```

How can I extract the arrays that have duplicate strings and get:

```
[["twitter.com", 9], ["twitter.com", 9], ["google.com", 11], ["twitter.com", 11],
 ["google.com", 12], ["twitter.com", 17], ["twitter.com", 18]]
```

Then add the value of the strings that are duplicate:

```
[["twitter.com", 64], ["google.com", 25]]
```

And end up with a new array :

```
[["twitter.com", 64], ["youtube.com", 31], ["google.com", 25],
 ["yahoo.com", 12],["paypal.me", 11]]
```

I tried:

```
array.select{|element| array.count(element) > 1 }
```

But was getting: `[["twitter.com", 9], ["twitter.com", 9]`

Comment: Have you attempted the problem yourself? What did you try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just count all sites with `each_with_object`:

```
array.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|(site, count), memo| memo[site] += count}
#=> {"twitter.com"=>64, "google.com"=>25, 
#    "paypal.me"=>11, "yahoo.com"=>12, "youtube.com"=>31}
```

You can simply convert the result to array by adding `to_a`, but IMO hash is enough for your issue.

Comment: How would you order new array value ascendent?

Comment: @mamesaye, `.sort_by {|_, v| -v}`

Comment: @mamesaye: That's not idiomatic, whenever you can, use `sort_by` instead of `sort`.

Answer (score 2):

Functional approach:

```
pairs.
  group_by { |k, v| k }.
  map { |k, ps| [k, ps.map { |k, v| v }.reduce(:+)] }.
  sort_by { |k, v| -v }
#=> [["twitter.com", 64], ["youtube.com", 31], ["google.com", 25],
#    ["yahoo.com", 12], ["paypal.me", 11]]
```

Comment: What do you mean by _functional_?

Comment: @Ilya: Functional programming, immutable data. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming https://www.slideshare.net/tokland/functional-programming-with-ruby-9975242

Comment: I know what community means by this term:) IMO, this code is about immutable data only.

Comment: It's all very subjective, ofc, but whenever a code uses immutable structures, modular abstractions, higher-order functions, ..., I think it may qualify as "functional". How would you write it in functional style with Ruby?